# PHP: File extension is empty when user uploads image with unallowed extension

Tags: php, html, forms, file-upload

I have a form on my website which besides everything else lets users to upload images to website.
HTML AND PHP:

```
<html>
<body>
<?php  
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
  $error = '';

  // Checking other input fields...

  // If anything else is valid, try to upload file (to avoid uploading useless c**p)
  if(isset($_FILES['file']) && $error == '' && $_FILES['file']){
    $file = $_FILES['file'];
    $file_name = $file['name'];
    $file_tmp = $file['tmp_name'];
    $file_size = $file['size'];
    $file_error = '';
    echo $file . $file_name . $file_tmp . $file_size;
    $file_ext = pathinfo($file_name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    if($file_ext != 'png' && $file_ext != 'jpg' && $file_ext != 'jpeg' && $file_ext != 'gif' && $file_ext != 'bmp'){
      $file_error .= "<br>Only png, jpg, jpeg, gif and bmp formats allowed!";
    }
    if($file_size > 1048576){ // << 1MB in bytes
      $file_error .= "<br>Maximum size is 1MB.";
    }
    if(empty($file_error)){
      $file_name_new = uniqid('', true) . '.' . $file_ext;
      $file_destination = 'img/usr/' . $file_name_new;
      if(rename($file_tmp, $file_destination)){
        // echo '<br>' . $file_destination;
      } else{$file_error .= '<br>Something went wrong while uploading file';}
    }
    echo $file_error;
  }
}
?>
  <form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Form</legend>
      <!-- Other input fields -->
      <div id="form_element">Upload image:</div>
      <input type="file" name="file"><span id="error"><small><?php echo $file_error;
  //echo $file . '<br>' .  $_FILES['file'] . '<br>' . $file_name . $file['name'];
  //echo '<br>' .  $file_tmp . '<br>' . $file['tmp_name'] . '<br>' . $file_size . '<br>' . $file['size'];
  ?></small></span>
      <div id="form_element">
        <input type="submit" value="Postita" id="submit">
      </div>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
```

There are multiple problems. When user uploads file which doesn't meet the requirementts(size, format etc), it's still uploaded even though **$error != ''**. When user doesn't fill in the file input field at all, code shouldn't enter file upload if statement(yes, I know, I don't know the right terms...), but "Something went wrong while uploading file" is still displayed. When image in unallowed format is submitted, it is still uploaded but the path looks like this /url/folder/img. - there is no file extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this ...

```
<?php
IF (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $err = "";
    $mimetypes = array('image/gif', 'image/jpeg', 'image/pjpeg', 'image/jpg', 'image/png', 'image/x-png'); 
    $imgexts = array('gif', 'jpeg', 'jpg', 'png'); 

    IF (!empty($_FILES['file']['name'])) {

        $img = $_FILES['file']['name'];
        $temp = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
        $ext = strtolower(substr(strrchr($_FILES['file']['name'], '.'), 1));// file ext.
        $info = @getimagesize($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']); 
        $imgw = $info[0]; // width 
        $imgh = $info[1]; // height 
        $mime = image_type_to_mime_type($info[2]);

        IF (!in_array($ext, $imgexts)) { 
            $err .="<li>File type (".$ext.") is not supported. (Only ".implode(", ",$imgexts).")</li>"; // Non-supported file type 
        }ELSE{
            // 
            IF (!in_array($mime, $mimetypes)) { 
                $err .="<li>Mime type (".$mime.") is not supported. (Only ".implode(", ",$mimetypes).")</li>"; // Non-supported mime type 
            }

        }

    }ELSE{ 
        $err ="<li>Select a file to upload (".implode(", ",$imgexts).")</li>";
    }


    IF (!empty($err)) {

        echo '<p>Errors:</p><ul>'.$err.'</ul>';

    }ELSE{

        // good to go

    }

}ELSE{

    // form not sumbitted 


}
?>
```